# how do i install bluez on ubuntu for development?

Tags: c, ubuntu, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

Beginner Question:

I'd like to use the BlueZ driver in my Raspberry Pi for a simple way to connect to an iPhone app I'm writing, but I'm trying to prototype it first on my Ubuntu boot (I dual boot a macbook pro w/ macOS sierra/Ubuntu 16.04). I am having trouble getting the bluetooth header "bluetooth.h" to show up in my c program.  I've tried doing sudo apt-get install bluez, but no bluetooth.h header shows up in my system after I perform this command.  Here are the includes for my prototype application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
```

when I `gcc` the program, I link to `-lbluetooth`, but my system can't find that lib either.

I should be using BlueZ for this, right? I've read that BlueZ is the official bluetooth stack for Linux, and I plan to put Raspbian Jesse on my raspberry pi; I'm just sanity checking that I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/common/development/bluez_programming

Looks like this tutorial had the answers, `sudo apt-get install bluez` installed the driver, but not the related development headers. 
Instead use `sudo apt-get install bluez libbluetooth-dev`.
Now `-lbluetooth` is found as a lib.